# hex to int and back gives different result

Tags: c#, hex

I got a MAC address as a hex string "0009A8040060" and I want to covert the last 3 bytes to int. Then I want to covert it back. I've thought I understood the basics with hex conversion - but apparently not!

My attempt thus far is

```
string endSerial = "0009A8040060".Substring(6);
int key = Convert.ToInt32(endSerial, 16);
```

Key is after that `262240`. This seems to be correct, but when I convert it using the code run on the server (which I cannot change)

```
int key = x; // receives over tcp. I´ve logged this int and its transferred ok!
string endSerial = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToUInt32(key))).Replace("-", "");
```

This gives endSerial = `60000400`.

I want it to be `00040060`. There seems to be some kind of reverse-issue? `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` is always true though.

Please help

Comment: I'm pretty sure `BitConverter.ToString(uint)` can't give you a 6-character string. Do you want `00040060` instead?

Comment: Yes, thats fine! @Sweeper. Edited.

Comment: Does `key.ToString("X8")` work for your purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you wouldn't use `BitConverter`, and would just do:

```
key.ToString("X6");
```

However, apparently you can't change the `BitConverter` code, so that's not an option.

---

`BitConveter`, as you have discovered, is outputting the bytes in little endian - the least significant byte first. However, when you are converting the string "040060" using `Convert.ToInt32`, it can be thought of as using big endian - the first byte `04` is being treated as the most significant byte. This is because `Convert.ToInt32` is designed to parse numbers written in the "everyday life" way, and big endian is how we write numbers in our everyday life. We write the most significant digit first.

Therefore, one way to fix this would be to switch the byte order of `key` before you send it:

```
int key = Convert.ToInt32(endSerial, 16);
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(key);
Array.Reverse(bytes); 
key = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0); // now it's in the right order!
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes apparently everything on the tcp-connection was sent with little endian. And they mistakenly used the same converter for this. So correct - as you say - is to send it as reversed.